# XMLQuery to INSERT/DELETE XML Elements

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, qxmlquery

I am trying to get a taste of XML manipulation in Oracle PLSQL. All the examples are of modifying XML stored in table column but I am trying to modify a XML variable.

Here is my code -

```
declare
l_xml XMLTYPE;
l_clob CLOB;

begin
l_xml:=XMLTYPE('<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<author>Per Bothner</author>
<author>Kurt Cagle</author>
<author>James Linn</author>
<author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web" cover="paperback">
<title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
<author>Erik T. Ray</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>');

select XMLQuery('copy $tmp := $p modify insert node 
<Pages>260 </Pages>
as last into $tmp/bookstore/book
return $tmp
'
passing l_xml as "p"
returning CONTENT).getCLobVal() into l_clob from dual;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_clob);

end;
```

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong- if possible can you please show couple of examples..

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Comment: a child node inserted under book node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning `Invalid target expression`.
Because this part `$tmp/bookstore/book` is returning collection of book node not a single element.

Few examples how to do this correctly
1) `$tmp/bookstore/book[@category eq "cooking"]` insert into book where attribute `category = "cooking"`
2) `$tmp/bookstore/book[2]` insert into 2-nd boook in your xml.
3) Insert pages into each books

```
XMLQuery('copy $tmp := $p modify 
(for $book in $tmp/bookstore/book return insert node <Pages>260 </Pages> into $book)
return $tmp'
passing l_xml as "p"
returning CONTENT)
```

Note
To get clob value from xml is better to use `xmlserialize`

Comment: Can you please explain what you did here -
XMLQuery('copy $tmp := $p modify 
(for $book in $tmp/bookstore/book return insert node <Pages>260 </Pages> into $book)
return $tmp'
passing l_xml as "p"
returning CONTENT)

I can see 2 return statements here.

Comment: Beauty of Xquery :), In this statement there are two block of code. 
1st- Internal (` for .. return `)  and 2-nd external `copy  modift return`. 
Return in 1st block is passing values to external block, Rturn in 2nd is passing value to "sql".

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help(I use Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production) and it is ok for me:

Here is the code that will insert tag 'Pages' in the right place:

```
select INSERTCHILDXML(l_xml,
   '/bookstore/book', 'Pages',
   XMLType('<Pages>260</Pages>')) into l_xml
   from dual;
```

And here is that inside of the begin-end:

```
/*from this part it is the same code as you have given us*/
declare
l_xml XMLTYPE;
l_clob CLOB;

begin
l_xml:=XMLTYPE('<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<author>Per Bothner</author>
<author>Kurt Cagle</author>
<author>James Linn</author>
<author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web" cover="paperback">
<title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
<author>Erik T. Ray</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>');
/*to this part it is the same code as you have given us*/

/*this is just one example how you can add <Pages> tag*/
select INSERTCHILDXML(l_xml,
   '/bookstore/book', 'Pages',
   XMLType('<Pages>260</Pages>')) into l_xml
   from dual;

/*this part is so you can see what you did :)*/
select l_xml.getClobVal() 
into l_clob from dual;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_clob);

end;
```

Comment: Thanks... This is one solution. But the implemention I am looking at using xmlquery because oracle has deprecated the use of standard oracle functions